# Meteor client login using LDAP and JWT

Tags: node.js, meteor, ldap, jwt, passport.js

I have a big CMS built with Meteor that until now used basic-auth to login as we didn't have more than one editor. However, more people will start working with it, so I am trying to create a login functionality through LDAP so any authorised employee can login with their username/password

I tried to do my best given poor documentation of WebApp.connectHandlers and the lack of content integrating passport with Meteor. I based my LDAP login code on express examples (assuming WebApp.connectHandlers.use() was the Meteor equivalent of Express' app.use())

The login part works, that is to query and verify the user through LDAP.

However I cannot figure how to identify the logged-in user when they make a Meteor.call( ).

What I have in mind at the moment is to send a JWT token back to the authenticated user, store it in a cookie or something, and whenever a Meteor.call( ) is made, the client passes the token as a parameter. Then I would be able to identify the caller and can for example store the username in the database as the person who made a certain change.

Good to mention that I am trying to avoid using Meteor's accounts system as the requirement is to use LDAP without creating any extra tables (that's why the complication of using those several packages together).

Here's my code, with working login but no idea how to pass back the token to the user.

Maybe my whole JWT logic is wrong, I would appreciate any help/suggestions.

```
var basicAuth = require("basic-auth");
var passport = require("passport");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var LdapStrategy = require("passport-ldapauth");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// Example of the real LDAP config
var OPTS = {
  server: {
    url: "ldap://address:port",
    bindDN: "admin",
    bindCredentials: "adminPassword",
    searchBase: "OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com",
    searchFilter: "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={{username}}))"
  },
  credentialsLookup: basicAuth
};

Meteor.startup(() => {
  passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(bodyParser.json());
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(passport.initialize());
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(
    "/",
    (req, res, next) => {
      // This part before the else is to trigger a basic auth popup to enter username/password
      let credentials = basicAuth(req);
      if (!credentials) {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        res.end("Access denied");
      } else {
        passport.authenticate(
          "ldapauth",
          {
            session: false
          },
          function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
              return next(err);
            }
            if (user) {
              var token = jwt.sign(
                { username: user.sAMAccountName },
                "someSecretString"
              );
              console.log("token", token);
              next();
            }
          }
        )(req, res, next);
      }
    },
    function(req, res) {
      console.log("debug point#2");
      res.send({ status: "ok" });
    }
  );
}
```